# trying to compiling typescript with reference to ng2-bootstrap with gulp in visual studio

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, ng2-bootstrap

Its been a couple of days now that i'm struggling with this problem and i hope somebody can help me out.

I am trying out Angular2 in a aspnet core project. The setup is that i am using a gulpfile.js to build .ts files and transfer everything to the wwwroot folder. Everything is working fine. typescript compiles, the files are transferred and even setting up a 'hello world' angular app works fine..

The problem starts when i try to add a reference to ng2-bootstrap. When i add this compiling typescript will error out with several errors such as this:

> node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/components/buttons/button-checkbox.directive.d.ts(14,22): error TS1005: '=' expected.

please access the sample i'm working on here: https://github.com/skyplusplus/ng2bootstrap-hell

how do i get rid of this problem?

-edit-
relevant gulpfile snippet:

`const tscConfig = require('./tsconfig.json');
var tsProject = typescript.createProject('tsconfig.json');
return tsProject
    .src(tscConfig.files)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(typescript(tsProject))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(targetPaths.app));`

Answer (score 0):

Configure gulp to ignore node_modules folder.
The `d.ts` files are type definition files which transpile to a js file with only a comment that references the js.map for debugging.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. I've tried several things such as adding the 'node_modules' folder in the exclude section of the tsconfig file and also setting up the files section in that file. I'm updating the question to show a snippet of what i have in the gulpfile.

Comment: Remove "typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts",
    "typings/globals/jasmine/index.d.ts",
    "typings/globals/jquery/index.d.ts",
    "typings/globals/node/index.d.ts",
    "typings/index.d.ts",
    "typings/modules/lodash/index.d.ts",   from the tsconfig.json file